# Mongo DB no conecta con C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

Tengo un proyecto en C# .NET en el cual referencie los drivers necesarios para usar mongo en este lenguaje, hasta ahí, todo correcto. Sin embargo, no hay ningún tipo de reacción por parte de la base de datos cuando ejecuto el siguiente código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected static IMongoClient _client;
    protected static IMongoDatabase _database;
    protected async Task Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoConnectionStr"].ConnectionString;
        //var mongoUrl = MongoUrl.Create(connectionString);

        _client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        _database = _client.GetDatabase("LinkedInDB");

        await insertarDato();
    }

    public async Task insertarDato()
    {
        var document = new BsonDocument
        {
            { "address" , "direccion" }
        };

        var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("users");
        await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);

    }

}
```

En el `Web.config` tengo la siguiente cadena de conexión:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MongoConnectionStr" 
      connectionString="mongodb://127.0.0.1:5665/"
        providerName="MongoConnectionStr"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Yo inicio `mongod` con el puerto que digo en la cadena de conexión, es decir el `5665` con: `mongod --port 5665`. Luego conecto con la base de datos al mismo puerto con: `mongo --port 5665` para verificar si hubo algún cambio después de ejecutar el proyecto Web, pero nada ocurre. Ya intenté cambiar `127.0.0.1` por `localhost`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descarga los paquetes desde el Nuget  yo instale la versión 2.4.4 , selecciona el MongoDB.Driver.GridFS este instalara los paquetes 
necesarios [image: MongoDbDriver], corri el mongo solo con

> Mongod

y verifique su estatus con [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) 
[image: Robomongo Conexion]

El código c# queda de la siguiente manera:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected static IMongoClient clienteLocal = new MongoClient();
        protected static IMongoDatabase dataLocal = clienteLocal.GetDatabase("base");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            insertar();
        }
        public void insertar() {
            string id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
            var documento = new BsonDocument
                            {
                                { "_id",id},
                                { "deviceId","123"},
                                { "date", DateTime.Now},
                                { "status", "Desconectado" }
                            };
            var collection_ = dataLocal.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("coleccion");
            collection_.InsertOneAsync(documento);
        }
        public void buscar(id) {
            var collection_ = dataLocal.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("coleccion");
            var filtro = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
            var datos = collection_.Find<BsonDocument>(filtro).FirstOrDefault();
            string nombre = datos["status"].ToString();
        }
        public void actualizar(id) {
            var res = dataLocal.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("coleccion");
            var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
            var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("status", "Conectado");
            var result = res.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
        }
        public void eliminar(id){        
            var collection = dataLocal.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("coleccion");
            var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
            var cuantos= collection.Find<BsonDocument>(filter).Count();
            if (cuantos == 1) { var delete = collection.DeleteManyAsync(filter); }     
        }
    }
}
```

quedando los datos de la siguiente manera

[image: Ejemplo][image: Ejemplo]

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió de mucho, en 13 horas te asigno la recompensa.

Comment: de nada es un placer haberte ayudado

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que como has cambiado el Page_Load verás que no te está entrando por el al haberlo declarado async.

Cambia el Load por esto:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            _client = new MongoClient(ConnectionString);
            _database = _client.GetDatabase("LinkedInDB");

            Task.Run(() => insertarDato());
        }
```

Así debería de insertártelo correctamente.